# Wake on LAN a laptop when the lid is closed

Tags: laptop, proxmox, wake-on-lan

I have an old laptop (Asus n56v) that I turned into a home lab by installing Proxmox hypervisor, it works well and also WOL (wake on LAN) work.

I need to store it lid-closed because I only manage it through the terminal from another host anyway.

I have edited `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and set `HandleLidSwitch=ignore`
 so now when I close the lid nothing happens which is good.

I can't seem to be able to have it wake on LAN when the lid is closed, only when it's opened.

the Proxmox is running under Debian stretch, running kernel 4.15.17-1-pve.

Comment: Perhaps because its in sleep-mode?

Comment: It's not in sleep mode in any stage, only turn on and then when work is done it's turned off completely (shutdown -h now)

Comment: Im sorry, but I don’t fully understand your sentence.

Comment: It is not in sleep mode, not in any way. It's only turned on and turned off. No sleep mode.

Comment: So it’s completely off?

Comment: It is, Powered off.

Comment: Then it's really normal for it, since a machine needs to be on for someone to wake it on LAN.

Comment: Well, I think you are missing something. The computer I being shutdown Everytime and wake on lan works perfectly! It's not being on or suspended, as I've said... The only difference here is that I want wake on lan to work when the lid is closed.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to so the same, and *yes it can be done*.

Debian's wiki provides two options:

> 1. For systems which should never attempt any type of suspension, these targets can be disabled at the systemd level with the following:
>
> `sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`
>
> 2. If you just want to prevent suspending when the lid is closed you can set the following options in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`:
>
> ```
> [Login]
> HandleLidSwitch=ignore
> HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
> ```

I've tested with two laptops.

- one laptop I set both `1.` & `2.`
- the other laptop I only set `2.`

WOL works in both cases, (laptops are powered off, their lids closed, WOL triggered --> both laptops (aka. proxmox nodes) boot up)

Very cool ;)

source: https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend